# CocoaLibSpotify storyboard error? App breaks when presenting loginviewcontroller

Tags: storyboard, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am using CocoaLibSpotify in my app, the app uses storyboard. When I try to present the loginviewcontroller like this:

```
[self presentViewController:[SPLoginViewController loginControllerForSession:[SPSession sharedSession]] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: nil URL argument'
```

In this file: SPLoginViewController

And this line:

```
NSURL *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SPLoginResources" withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundlePath];
```

What could cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [CocoaLibSpotify ReadMe](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/) under the "Building - iOS" section, you must include the `SPLoginResources.bundle` bundle supplied with the library in your project.